# Check if Meteor method called in testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, meteor, chai

I would like to check if a Meteor server method is being called using Chai and Mocha for testing. Here's my code:

test.js:

```
    let {chargeUser} = Meteor.methods;

    it('should call charge user', () => {
        let {_id} = User.findOne();
        plan.charge(_id);

        chai.expect(chargeUser.calledOnce);
    });
```

charge function:

```
    charge(userId) {
        Meteor.call('chargeUser', userId, this._id);
    }
```

I would like to verify that the Meteor method chargeUser is called, but I have had little luck verifying that this Meteor method is called. If someone could point me in the right location, it'd be much appreciated.